# TV episode where aliens wanted to take all the black people and earth had a vote to decide their fate

Tags: story-identification, tv

Does anyone remember an episode of the Outer Limits or some other show where aliens came to earth and wanted to take all of the black people with them to avert the world's destruction and the world held an election to decide the fate of black people. The world voted to send black people away with the aliens. At the end of the episode, we learned the black people were headed to utopia, while the rest of the world would suffer without them.

I remember watching this episode a long time ago and I can't find it anywhere online. If you have any information please reply, I would like to know I'm having the Mandela effect happening to me right now.

Answer (score 9):

You're likely referring to the short story [*The Space Traders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Traders) by Derrick Bell. It was anthologised in the TV movie [Cosmic Slop](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109487/). You can watch the segment in full below.